# How to fix "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-slider

Currently making a Site with HTML, CSS and JS in stackblitz.com and im trying to add an image slider into one of my pages. I've tried multiple methods online but the same issue happends, I input the code and the actual image slider works fine on it's respective page but the Index page won't load and instead displays this:

Error in /script.js (26:11)
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Here is my code so far

Html

```
<body>
 <div id="arrow-left" class="arrow"></div>
 <div class="slide slide1"></div>
 <div class="slide slide2"></div>
 <div class="slide slide3"></div>
 <div id="arrow-right" class="arrow"></div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.slide {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-left: 30%;
}
  
.slide1 {
    background-image: url(
  "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20210812221217/pic1.png");
  background-size: 350px 300px;
}
.slide2 {
  background-image: url(
  "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20210812221254/pic2.png");
  background-size: 350px 300px;
}
.slide3 {
  background-image: url(
  "https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20210812221322/pic3.png");
  background-size: 350px 300px;
}
.arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 54%;
  margin-top: -35px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}
#arrow-left {
  border-width: 10px 15px 10px 0;
  border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
  left: 67%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
  
#arrow-right {
  border-width: 10px 0 10px 15px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff;
  right: 7%;
  margin-right: 20px;
  top: 55%;
}
```

JS

```
let sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll(".slide"),
arrowLeft = document.querySelector("#arrow-left"),
arrowRight = document.querySelector("#arrow-right"),
current = 0;
  
function reset() {
    for (let i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
        sliderImages[i].style.display = "none";
        }
}
  
function startSlide() {
    reset();
    sliderImages[0].style.display = "block";
}
  
function slideLeft() {
    reset();
    sliderImages[current - 1].style.display = "block";
    current--;
}
  
function slideRight() {
    reset();
    sliderImages[current + 1].style.display = "block";
    current++;
}
  
arrowLeft.addEventListener("click", function () {
if (current === 0) {
    current = sliderImages.length;
}
slideLeft();
});
  
arrowRight.addEventListener("click", function () {
    if (current === sliderImages.length - 1) {
        current = -1;
    }
    slideRight();
});
  
startSlide();
```

Sorry in advance if my code is really messy i've just been looking most of this stuff up as I go. How could I fix this? I suppose its a JS thing which is probably the part of this I know the least about.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: After putting the script inside of the HTML file and below the actual HTML Body it made the Index page work, thanks!

Comment: hi, @epascarello pointed you in the right direction. 

the thing is, the browser is executing that javascript code before the DOM is even created. It is normal that your selector could not find the element you're trying to bind an event handler. This is why in some libraries (like jquery) the event registration is done after windo.onload (or in some cases onDomReady).

Comment: @Destin242, that resolution you used, is not the best solution. it may work or it may not work. in order to be sure that your js code is able to find the your desired dom elements, you need to make sure that the dom is initialized. make your bindings when you are 100% that is true. folow this best practice, and you'll spare yourself of many hours of pain. trust me, been there.